# Подскажите пожалуйста почему при ресайзе не меняется ширина первого и последнего slider_item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста пишу плагин, по задумке при ресайзе страницы ширина элементов и отступ слева должны пересчитываться, но  почему-то не меняется ширина первого и последнего slider_item которые вставлены в html через jQuery. Как это исправить ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.slider-box').simpleSlider();

});



(function($){

$.fn.simpleSlider = function() {

 return this.each(function(){  

  resized=false;
  var thisEl =$(this);
  slider = thisEl.children('div','ul','img'),
  slideWidth = thisEl.width(),
  slider_item = slider.children(),
  slideCount = slider_item.length,
  next = $(document).find('.nextBtn'),
  prev = $(document).find('.prevBtn');   
    sliderInterval = 3300,                             
    animateTime = 1000,                                
    course = 1,                                        
    margin = - slideWidth;                            
 

  slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  slider_item.last().clone().prependTo(slider);   // Копия последнего слайда помещается в начало.
  slider_item.eq(1).clone().appendTo(slider);   // Копия первого слайда помещается в конец.  
  slider.css('margin-left', -slideWidth);        

 


  function nextSlide(){                                 // 
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, sliderInterval);
  }



$(window).resize(function() {  
  slideWidth = thisEl.width();
    slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  resized=true;
 }).resize()

  function animate(){
   if (resized) {
    var widthslider=slider_item.width(); //старая ширина слайдеов
    var numslider=parseInt(-margin/widthslider); //номер текущего слайдера
    slider_item.css('width',slideWidth); //меняем ширину слайдеров
    margin = -slideWidth * numslider; //считаем смещение слайдеров слева
    slider.css('margin-left', margin); //меняем смещение слайдов слева
    resized=false;
  }
    if (margin==-slideCount*slideWidth-slideWidth){     
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth});         
      margin=-slideWidth*2;
    }else if(margin==0 && course==-1){                
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth*slideCount});
      margin=-slideWidth*slideCount+slideWidth;
    }else{                                           
    margin = margin - slideWidth*(course);             
    }
    slider.animate({'marginLeft':margin},animateTime); 
  }
 
  function sliderStop(){                              
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
 

 
  nextSlide();                                          

})

};


})(jQuery)
```

```css
.slider-box{
  max-width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slider{
  position:relative;
  width: 10000px;
}
.slider_item {
 float: left;
}

.slider_item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider">

  <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maxresdefault-2-6.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdni.rt.com/russian/images/2017.04/article/58fe599bc3618843468b47c1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdn2.img.sputnik-georgia.com/images/23488/54/234885475.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://i2.rozetka.ua/goods/4684342/41683632_images_4684342448.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://thewire.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/space-1728314_1920.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
    <span class="bullets"></span>
    <span class="prevBtn"></span>
    <span class="nextBtn"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После создания копий слайдов нужно переопределить slider_item = slider.children();

PS. Я так и не понял зачем нужно добавлять последний слайд в начало. Он в анимации не участвует. Хватает копии первого слайда в конце.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.slider-box').simpleSlider();

});



(function($){

$.fn.simpleSlider = function() {

 return this.each(function(){  

  resized=false;
  var thisEl =$(this);
  slider = thisEl.children('div','ul','img'),
  slideWidth = thisEl.width(),
  slider_item = slider.children(),
  slideCount = slider_item.length,
  next = $(document).find('.nextBtn'),
  prev = $(document).find('.prevBtn');   
    sliderInterval = 3300,                             
    animateTime = 1000,                                
    course = 1,                                        
    margin = - slideWidth;                            
 

  slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  slider_item.last().clone().prependTo(slider);   // Копия последнего слайда помещается в начало.
  slider_item.eq(1).clone().appendTo(slider);   // Копия первого слайда помещается в конец.  
  slider.css('margin-left', -slideWidth);        
  slider_item = slider.children();
 


  function nextSlide(){                                 // 
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, sliderInterval);
  }



$(window).resize(function() {  
  slideWidth = thisEl.width();
    slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  resized=true;
 }).resize()

  function animate(){
   if (resized) {
    var widthslider=slider_item.width(); //старая ширина слайдеов
    var numslider=parseInt(-margin/widthslider); //номер текущего слайдера
    slider_item.css('width',slideWidth); //меняем ширину слайдеров
    margin = -slideWidth * numslider; //считаем смещение слайдеров слева
    slider.css('margin-left', margin); //меняем смещение слайдов слева
    resized=false;
  }
    if (margin==-slideCount*slideWidth-slideWidth){     
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth});         
      margin=-slideWidth*2;
    }else if(margin==0 && course==-1){                
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth*slideCount});
      margin=-slideWidth*slideCount+slideWidth;
    }else{                                           
    margin = margin - slideWidth*(course);             
    }
    slider.animate({'marginLeft':margin},animateTime); 
  }
 
  function sliderStop(){                              
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
 

 
  nextSlide();                                          

})

};


})(jQuery)
```

```css
.slider-box{
  max-width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slider{
  position:relative;
  width: 10000px;
}
.slider_item {
 float: left;
}

.slider_item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-box">
  <div class="slider">

  <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maxresdefault-2-6.jpg" alt="" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdni.rt.com/russian/images/2017.04/article/58fe599bc3618843468b47c1.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://cdn2.img.sputnik-georgia.com/images/23488/54/234885475.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  <div class="slider_item"> 
     <img src="https://i2.rozetka.ua/goods/4684342/41683632_images_4684342448.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider_item">  
     <img src="https://thewire.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/space-1728314_1920.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
    <span class="bullets"></span>
    <span class="prevBtn"></span>
    <span class="nextBtn"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!!! "Я так и не понял зачем нужно добавлять последний слайд в начало. Он в анимации не участвует. Хватает копии первого слайда в конце." по идее это нужно если слайдер в другую сторону будет ластиться или если кнопкой назад листать

Comment: Даже если назад листать анимацию можно и без него сделать. Если листаем с первого на последний, то переходим на копию первого в конце и листаем на последний.

Comment: сделал так как ты написал )